# CListCtrl - how to find it is selected

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, clistctrl

I have got a CDialog Class, inside which there are two ClistCtrl classes.
I want to find out which of the listCtrl's is selected at the moment.
say, listCtrl A and B. Even when I move between A and B, suppose first I go to A and select a row. Then even when I go to B and select an item there, item in A remains selected as I don't come to know that I have gone in other list.

Any suggestions, how I can find this.

Answer (score 1):

If understand you correctly, you need to know which one of list boxes has a focus.  You could do that by calling `GetFocus()`, it returns a pointer to the focused control.

The problem you might have though is when your dialog is not an active window and then focus would be somewhere else.  In this case you should be tracking `WM_SETFOCUS` and `WM_KILLFOCUS` messages and keeping record of which of the list boxes was activated last.  In MFC there are callbacks `CWnd::OnSetFocus` and `CWnd::OnKillFocus` that could be used to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way of doing this. I can register for NM_Click notifications on both the lists
When list A is selected, I set curSel of list B to -1 and vice versa.

Comment: Keep in mind that users can also activate controls with the keyboard, for example with the TAB key.  In this case your solution will not work.

Comment: so, is there an way i can register for keyboard notifications?

Comment: One thing you could do is subclass `CListCtrl` and override `OnSetFocus` and `OnKillFocus`.  This will let you track both keyboard and mouse events.